# Several errors when integrating react router to React Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm trying to utilize the React router package in my React + Redux application, and doing so gives me the following errors:

`Unexpected key "listings" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "routing". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accounts' of undefined`

`ReactDOMComponentTree.js?1a2c:107Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$c5skqk6ty0f83o5hzvf0i19k9' of null`

Here is my code:

**initialState.js:**

```
export default {
    listings: {
        status: '',
        searchBy: '',
        accounts: []
    }
};
```

**index.js (root reducer file):**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**routes.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={App}/>
  </Route>
);
```

**configureStore.js:**

```
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    // Add other middleware on this line...
    applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant(), thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f // add support for Redux dev tools
    )
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers').default; // eslint-disable-line global-require
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

**index.js (entry point for app):**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import initialState from './reducers/initialState';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import mockTableData from './data/MockTableData';
import App from './components/App';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

const listings = objectAssign({}, initialState.listings, {accounts: mockTableData});
const initial = objectAssign({}, initialState, {listings});
const store = configureStore(initial);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks pretty odd... where's `createStore` from the redux library?

Comment: It's in my `configureStore` file that I imported - I have just added that code into the question.

Comment: well the way you have it, redux would be expecting a reducer with the key `listings`, but you only have one reducer `routing`. How were you expecting to access your listing state without a relevant reducer?

Comment: I'm just starting this application and hadn't created the `listingsReducer` yet.  I just added it in with only a default case that returns the state and the problem was not resolved.

Comment: can you post your updated `combineReducers?

Comment: Nevermind, that did it.  Thanks!